# iOS capture audio playback into a file

Tags: ios, audio, record

I'd like to know if it's possible to record an audio playback into a file in ios without using microphone. In another word, is it possible to capture the audio playback "raw data" into a file?

I tried the AVAudioRecorder, but there is no option to record without using the microphone. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

Your question is too generic, and the above answers it.

But, more specifically, as with most things there are several approaches possible, the final solution will depend on your needs. For example, if you're constrained to, or have a preference for "playing" via `AVPlayer`, you can use an `MTAudioProcessingTap` (See apple's AudioTapProcessor example) to gain access to the "Raw Data". Similarly, you can build an `AudioGraph` and use an `AudioUnit`  as the "player" along with `Audio File Services` to both read (which will give you access to the "Raw Data") and write the file. There are various alternatives depending on your needs and, in some cases, your preference. Providing some code or a better explanation of your needs, might solicit a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thanks.Yes, my question is too generic because I don't how to describe it.Anyway I'll study what you talked about.